# why do it says its already defined using constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, constructor

````
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    public class midterm {
        static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Account myAccount = new Account();
            int user_choice;
    
            do{
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("1) New Billing");
                System.out.println("2) Add Existing Billing");
                System.out.println("3) View Billing Account ID");
                System.out.println("4) View By Date");
                System.out.println("5) Update Existing Billing");
                System.out.println("6) Delete Billing Account");
                System.out.println("7) Display All Account");
                System.out.println("8) Exit");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Enter choice [1-8]: ");
                user_choice = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (user_choice) {
                
                case 1:
                    String id;
                    System.out.print("Enter Billing Code: ");
                    String bc = scanner.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Billing Date(dd/mm/yyyy): ");
                    String bd = scanner.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Customer Name: ");
                    String customerName = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Customer Address: ");
                    String customerAddress = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Customer Number: ");
                    String customerNumber = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Period To: ");
                    String periodT = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Period From: ");
                    String periodF = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Present Reading: ");
                    double presentR = scanner.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter Previous Reading: ");
                    double previousR = scanner.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter Previous Balance: ");
                    double previousB = scanner.nextDouble();
                    //myAccount.openNewAccount(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB);
                    System.out.println("Account was created and it has the following number: " + myAccount.openNewAccount(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB));
                    break;
    
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int anum = scanner.nextInt();
    
                    
    
    
                }
            }while(user_choice!='6');
        }
  
        static class Account{
            private userAccount[] account;
            private int numOfAccounts = 10;
        
        
        public Account(){
            account = new userAccount[10];
            numOfAccounts = 0;
        }
 
 ```
````

this is the part where the problem exist, it worked the first time but now it is not working, i am new to constructors and classes to how this works. It says required: no arguments found: String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,double,double,doublereason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length, i just want it to pass the inputed datas under the randomStr which gives a random acct number
```

```
        public int openNewAccount(String id,String bc,String bd,String customerName,String customerAddress,String customerNumber,String periodT,String periodF,double presentR,double previousR,double previousB){
            
            int min = 1000;
            int max = 9999;
            int randomStr = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    
            userAccount randomStr = new userAccount(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB);
            account[numOfAccounts] = randomStr;
            numOfAccounts++;
            return randomStr.getAccountNum();
        }
    
    }
```

```
        this is my userAccount class where the user is stored, it worked the first time but now it doesn't
```

```
 static class userAccount{
            private int accountNum;
            private String id;
            private String bc;
            private String bd;
            private String customerName;
            private String customerAddress;
            private String customerNumber;
            private String periodT;
            private String periodF;
            private double presentR;
            private double previousR;
            private double previousB;
            private  static int noOfAccounts=0;
    
            public int userAccount(String idN,String bcN,String bdN,String customerName1,String customerAddress1,String customerNumber1,String periodT1,String periodF1,double presentR1,double previousR1,double previousB1){
                
                id = idN;
                bc = bcN;
                bd = bdN;
                customerName = customerName1;
                customerAddress = customerAddress1;
                customerNumber = customerNumber1;
                periodT = periodT1;
                periodF = periodF1;
                presentR = presentR1;
                previousR = previousR1;
                previousB = previousB1;
                noOfAccounts++;
                accountNum = noOfAccounts;
            }
    
            public int getAccountNum(){
                return accountNum;
            } 
    
    }
       
    }   
    
  
    this is not yet finished just checking if it works, ive been tweaking this but cant really understand why it says my randomStr is already defined.
```

this is the error it shows in the compiler.

```
midterm.java:80: error: variable randomStr is already defined in method openNewAccount(String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,double,double,double)
        userAccount randomStr = new userAccount(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB);
                    ^
midterm.java:80: error: constructor userAccount in class userAccount cannot be applied to given types;
        userAccount randomStr = new userAccount(id,bc,bd,customerName,customerAddress,customerNumber,periodT,periodF,presentR,previousR,previousB);
                                ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

Comment: `public int userAccount` is not a constructor, it is a method returning an `int`. And you have two `randomStr`, one is an `int`, one is a `userAccount`, neither are a `Str`ing as the name would suggest. And please start classes (and types in general) with an uppercase letter, otherwise they are hard to distinguish from variables. Downvote for not understanding two very clear compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying "variable randomStr is already defined" because that variable is being defined two times like in (simplified):

```
public void someMethod() {  // or constructor, or any block

    int randomStr;
    String randomStr;    // SAME name as previous line

}
```

<sup>WRONG code! Just to make the error more apparent, it is NOT intended to be a solution</sup>

You cannot define a local variable two times (not even with same type) in the same block - this is not allowed by [Java Language Spcification 6.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4-210):

> **It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable v is used to declare a new variable within the scope of v,** ...